# A suitable metric for the consistency of a model's outputs

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I have a question about a metric for the consistency of outputs.
Suppose I have a model called $M$. I have an input space called $X$ with $X = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{50}\}$ where there is a very slight difference between $x$'s in $I$. Each time, I feed my model $M$ with an $x_i$ from $X$, I get a corresponding output $y_i$. Therefore, I have an output space called $Y$ with $Y = \{y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n\}$. Based on some criteria (which is not relevant to this question) each output $y_i$ will be either correct or wrong. Let's assume the set of all correct outputs to be $C$.

In the first experiment, out of 50 outputs, 30 of them were correct and out of these 30 correct outputs, 20 of them were identical. Let's call the set of these correct identical $I$ and call this whole experiment $E_1$. So:

with $E_1$ we have

$|X| = |Y| = 50$

$|C| = 30$

$|I| = 20$

I repeated the above experiment 2 more times with the same inputs. So, overall I have 3 experiments that are $E_1, E_2 $ and $E_3$ where with $E_2$, out of 50 outputs, 40 of them were correct and out of those 40 correct outputs, 10 were identical; therefore:

with $E_2$ we have:

$|X| = |Y| = 50$

$|C| = 40$

$|I| = 10$

and finally with $E_3$, out of 50 outputs, 20 of them were correct and out of those 20 correct outputs, 15 were identical; which means:

with $E_3$ we have:

$|X| = |Y| = 50$

$|C| = 20$

$|I| = 15$

My question is how to assess the consistency of the model in terms of the identicality of its outputs in all 3 experiments. Should it be like $\frac{20}{50} \times \frac{10}{50} \times \frac{15}{50} = 0.06$ or $\frac{20}{30} \times \frac{10}{40} \times \frac{15}{20} = 0.125$? In other words, in each fraction corresponding to each experiment, should the denominator be the total number of outputs or the total number of *correct* outputs? Would be great if any relevant references be suggested.

Comment: What is the purpose of assessing the consistency of the outputs? In other words, what is the task after obtaining the consistency of the outputs? Knowing this will allow you to determine what kind of metric to use.

Comment: @mhdadk I want to evaluate my model in terms of how consistent (or similar) a set of outputs are when I feed the model with a set of inputs that are slightly different from each other. E.g, I have _x_ as input and _y_ as the corresponding output, if I change _x_ to _x'_ (where the change is very small), my ideal output will be still _y_ but the model doesn’t always yield _y_, it may produce _y'_ or _y''_. So I want to have a metric that shows how the model's performance was in producing consistent outputs and therefore how reliable the model was.

Comment: If Y were quantitative, some variants of ICC (intra class correlation) are ment to measure voter (= model in your case) consistency. As you speak of "correct" or "wrong" Y values, it seems that your Y is categorial. Presumable there is an equivalent to ICC for categorial responses, although I do not know it.